# Pandas - DF: Creating a % DF based on frequencies from a different DF

Tags: python, pandas

Basically I have a table on this shape:

| customer_id | month_1 | month_2 | month_3 | month_4 | month_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XXX0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| XXX1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| XXX2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| XXX3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| XXX4 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| XXX5 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

It shows whether a customer was default on a specific month and for how long he stayed as default. My objective is to create a new table which represents the default % evolution, it would have the following shape:

| months | month_1 | month_2 | month_3 | month_4 | month_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| month_1 | 100% | 100% | 50% | 0% | 0% |
| month_2 | 0 | 100% | 50% | 0% | 0% |
| month_3 | 0 | 0 | 100% | 66% | 33% |
| month_4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 100% | 100% |
| month_5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 100% |

They call this a Cohort Analysis. The idea is to visualize how the % of defaults in a specific month performs through time, as an example: On month_3 there are 3 new default clientes (the rest of them comes from other months), so on the next month the number of default from month_3 is only 2, which is 66% from the original ones. The same idea goes for all months.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how approach this?
I've been thinking on using pandas apply function for each month, checking the total and the fractions across time and inserting on the new DF, is this a good approach??

Comment: can you give me detail on how to construct the new table, I don't see how the costumer_id column is used

Comment: @Kenan That's where the percentage comes in. Take `month_1` for example, there are two costumer(?) default (1) in `month_1`, both of them stay default in `month_2`, only one stay default in `month_3`, none in the later months. Hence the numbers in row `month_1`.

Comment: that still doesn't explain the 33%, 66% or 50%

Comment: On month_3 there are 3 default new clientes (the rest of them comes from other months),   so on the next month the number of default from month_3 is only 2, which is 66% from the original ones.

Comment: @Supertramp I recommend you add the two explanations to the question. That'd help the question not to be downvoted/closed.

Comment: just did it, if there is any other way I can improve my question, just let me know :)